# how I can move this numbers using selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hello I have no idea how to start, I got just example(http://demoqa.com/sortable), how I can change the position of the numbers 1-2-3-4;2-1-3-4; I must do it like a test in selenium webdriver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### C#

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using System.Diagnostics;
```

```
using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver())
{
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://demoqa.com/sortable");
    var elementOne = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#demo-tabpane-list > div > div:nth-child(1)"));
    var elementTwo = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#demo-tabpane-list > div > div:nth-child(2)"));

    var actionChain = new Actions(driver);
    actionChain
         .ClickAndHold(elementTwo)
         .MoveToElement(elementOne)
         .MoveByOffset(0, 10)
         .Release()
         .Perform();

     elementOne = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#demo-tabpane-list > div > div:nth-child(1)"));
     elementTwo = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#demo-tabpane-list > div > div:nth-child(2)"));

    Debug.Assert(elementOne.Text.ToLower() == "two");
    Debug.Assert(elementTwo.Text.ToLower() == "one");
}
```

### Python

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Drivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("http://demoqa.com/sortable")

first_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#demo-tabpane-list > div > div:nth-child(1)")
second_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#demo-tabpane-list > div > div:nth-child(2)")

action_chains = ActionChains(driver)
action_chains.drag_and_drop(second_element, first_element).perform()

first_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#demo-tabpane-list > div > div:nth-child(1)")
second_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#demo-tabpane-list > div > div:nth-child(2)")

assert first_element.text.casefold() == 'two'
assert second_element.text.casefold() == 'one'

driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

I used documentation from https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/ and https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/

I noticed one issue involving the C# version, that I had to use a series of actions and ensure that the element was in a slightly different location to work correctly. The Python version didn't require this.

I did not know what unit testing framework to use for C#, so I used System.Diagnostics.